# Make asmx request on behalf of authenticated SAML user

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx, wif

Using Windows Identity Foundation I have a user who is successfully logged in and able to request pages.  But there is an issue on any page that relies upon a asmx web service request to a WIF protected resource.

Is there a way to add SAML information to an asmx request similar to how you would add it to a WCF request?

Comment: Is the web service protected by WIF? Passing authentication into a web service is always tricky (WCF can handle it much better).

Comment: The web service is protected by WIF.  There is a decent chance that we'll just move it over to WCF since it should have used WCF originally.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a custom header in your soap messages.

you can then use that to specify the user credentials from which the action is being performed.

It's a fairly advanced subject this ...

2D00-a-solution.aspx">http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2006/04/26/Adding-custom-headers-to-every-WCF-call-*2D00*-a-solution.aspx

but the idea is that you are kind of adding a constraint to the calls that the service accepts shaping the packet to ensure that the credentials are wrapped up.

the other way of course is to go back to basics and basically build a lump of xml (soap packet) and then use the request and response classes to manually process the information (not ideal)